# How to create html page via module drupal 7

Tags: theming, routes

I am new in Drupal. I have created  a form which saves the values to custom table how ever I want to display those items in a tabular format. Does any one know how  to create a custom page where I can display those items.

This is what I tried:
in module file

```
<?php $menu_items['user/campaigns/new_campaign'] = array(
        'title' => 'Campaigns',
        'type'=> MENU_CALLBACK, 
        'page callback' => 'create_campaign_form2',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'file' => 'campaigns.create_campaign2.inc',
        'weight' => 1,
    ); ?>
```

in campaigns.create_campaign2.inc file:

```
<?php function create_campaign_form2()
{
    echo 'Some HTML here';

}
?>
```

But it displays only displays the text, the entire css is removed please let me know what should I do. 
Sorry if the question is too basic.

Comment: you should add an `return;` statement to the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Use Drupal's [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7.). Basically your code will look like this:

```
<?php 
    $menu_items['user/campaigns/new_campaign'] = array(
      'title' => 'Campaigns',
      'type'=> MENU_CALLBACK, 
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('create_campaign_form2');
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      'file' => 'campaigns.create_campaign2.inc',
      'weight' => 1,
    );
?>

<?php
   $form = array();
   $form['selected'] = array(
     '#type' => 'select',
     '#title' => t('Selected'),
     '#options' => array(
        0 => t('No'),
        1 => t('Yes'),
     ),
     '#default_value' => 'Maybe',
     '#description' => t('Set this to <em>Yes</em> if you would like this category to be selected by default.'),
   );
   return $form;
?>
```

Notice the use of drupal_get_form() in the menu hook. This function takes the return value of create_campaign_form2, which it expects to be a PHP array, as an argument and uses that data to build the markup of the form.

This particular example will generate a form with only a select drop down. But check out the [complete Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7) for all (and there are A LOT) of the options and settings you have available to build your form. It might be intimidating at first, but the idea is quite simple: you create a PHP array that represents your form and then drupal_get_form() turns that array into a secure and well structured form. ALWAYS use the Form API to build forms in Drupal.

Comment: +1. Probably OP wants to *display* items saved from a form that is already built ?

Comment: looking at the question date, I'm wondering how on the earth I came here.